# React checkbox feature with only single selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, materialize

I want to figure out whether my code is wrong or a bug. I think there is no problem, but it does not work...

The code I used is:
https://codepen.io/cadenzah/pen/wvwYLgj?editors=0010

```
class ItemView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      options: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Item 1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Item 2"
      }],
      optionSelected: 2
    }
  }

  toggleCheckbox(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id)
    if (this.state.optionSelected === e.target.id) {
      this.setState({
        optionSelected: undefined
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({ optionSelected: e.target.id })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <ItemList
            options={this.state.options}
            optionSelected={this.state.optionSelected}
            toggleCheckbox={(e) => this.toggleCheckbox(e)} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const ItemList = ({ options, optionSelected, toggleCheckbox }) => {
  return (
    <div className="col s12">
      {
        options.map((option, index) => (
          <Item
            key={index}
            option={option}
            checked={(optionSelected === (index + 1) ? true : false)}
            toggleCheckbox={toggleCheckbox} />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const Item = ({ option, checked, toggleCheckbox }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-content">
        <p><label htmlFor={option.id}>
          <input 
            className="filled-in"
            type="checkbox"
            id={option.id}
            onChange={toggleCheckbox}
            checked={(checked ? "checked" : "")} />
          <span>{option.id}. {option.name}</span>
          </label></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### Code explaination:

React code, with `materialize-css` used.

It is a simple checkbox feature with multiple items, restricted to select only one item. So, if I check one of them, every item except for what I just selected will be unchecked automatically. If I uncheck what I just checked, every item will stay unchecked.

The core logic is: in `<ItemList />` component, there is a *conditional props* that determines whether each item has to be checked or not. It compares the id, and hand in `true` or `false` into its children. That `checked` props is used in `<Item />` component to set the `checked` attribute of `<input>`.

Strange thing is, as I set default choice in the initial state, when I just run the application, the check feature works as I expected. But if I click one of them, it does not work.

What is the problem of it?

Comment: I think you should try to use refs, IDs don't play nice with react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target.id` is a `string` while `index` is a number. When you do a `===` comparison the type is also checked and these are not the same. This results in checked always being false after the initial state (which you set yourself as an int)

Comment: That is a good point. I forgot that `id` attribute is a `string` value. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the selected option is the checked one like this:

```
checked={optionSelected === option.id}
```

And then you simply get it into your input like this:

```
<input checked={checked} />
```

Also, make sure to change your state ids into strings (the DOM element id is of type string):

```
  options: [{
    id: '1',
    name: "Item 1"
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: "Item 2"
  }],
  optionSelected: '2'
```

https://codepen.io/AndrewRed/pen/gOYBVPZ?editors=0010

Answer (score 2):

```
class ItemView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      options: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Item 1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Item 2"
      }],
      optionSelected: 2
    }
  }

  toggleCheckbox(e) {

    this.setState({
      optionSelected : e.target.id
    })
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <ItemList
            options={this.state.options}
            optionSelected={this.state.optionSelected}
            toggleCheckbox={(e) => this.toggleCheckbox(e)} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const ItemList = ({ options, optionSelected, toggleCheckbox }) => {

  return (
    <div className="col s12">
      {
        options.map((option, index) => (
          <Item
            key={index}
            option={option}
            checked={(optionSelected === (index + 1) ? true : false)}
            toggleCheckbox={toggleCheckbox} 
            optionSelected = {optionSelected}
            />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const Item = ({ option, checked, toggleCheckbox,optionSelected }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-content">
        <p><label htmlFor={option.id}>
          <input 
            className="filled-in"
            type="checkbox"
            id={option.id}
            onChange={toggleCheckbox}
            checked={option.id == optionSelected ? "checked" : ""} />
          <span>{option.id}. {option.name}</span>
          </label></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function tick() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <ItemView />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

tick()
```

COPY PASTE AND RUN